# gradle build property in application code

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

I want to fire my acceptance test for some predefined environments. I have a file env.groovy with `env{ dev{...}, test{...}}` config.
I pass one of the properties this way in `build.gradle`:

```
test {
    enabled = false
    systemProperties = System.getProperties()
    systemProperties['foo'] = 'bar'
}
```

when I fire a test like this `FooValTest`

```
  @Test
    public void testFooVal(){
        assertEquals("bar", System.getProperty("foo"));
    }
```

it fails.
source: https://github.com/mvcatsifma/spring-ctx-props-file/blob/master/src/test/java/AppTest.java

this flag `enabled=false` makes a difference - why is that? it doesn't allow sysProperties change?

I want to keep `enabled=false` because it's inherited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the actual system properties here, you're just modifying the returned data structure.

From my experience, the following works:

```
test {
  systemProperty "foo", "bar"
}
```

Enabled just enables or disables the task (section 14.8.3 at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html)

Comment: nope, that's not the case. I've found solution there was also `dependsOn drivers.collect { tasks["someTask"]}` and properties were taken from there

Comment: Well I guess the reason this works is because Test tasks have a special method "systemProperty" that sets your system properties on the test JVM that gradle launches. It's not the same as the Gradle JVM that is doing your build.